# python: create raw string of variables

Tags: python

i have to read a line in which i looking for pattern like

```
width:40
height :50
left : 60
right: 70
```

following  found the required pattern

```
line = "width:40"
match = re.search(r'width\s*:\s*\d+', line)
```

in above code i have hard-coded the regex pattern for `width`

i have stored all four variables in array `key_word = ['width', 'height', 'left', 'right']`

i want to search for pattern for all these variable like

```
for key in key_word:
        match = re.search(key, line)
```

the problem is how can i make this `key` a raw string which will be a pattern like

```
r'width\s*:\s*\d+'
r'height\s*:\s*\d+'
r'left\s*:\s*\d+'
r'right\s*:\s*\d+'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following:

```
key_word = ['width', 'height', 'left', 'right']
regex_template = r'{}\s*:\s*\d+'
for key in key_word:
    print re.search(regex_template.format(key), line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use a generic regex:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*:\s*(\d+)', text)
```

`matches` will be a list of `(key, value)` tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `split` (or `partition`) and `strip`?

```
for line in lines:
    key, sep, value = line.partition(':')
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()
```

If you're really needing to use regular expressions, you can format them, too:

```
r'%s\s*:\s*\d+' % 'width'
```

Or for each key:

```
regexes = [r'%s\s*:\s*\d+' % key for key in ['width', 'height', ...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this task. See other answers.

However if you insist, you can create one dynamically using [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
import re

key_word = ['width', 'height', 'left', 'right']

myre = r'({})\s*:\s*(\d+)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, key_word)))
```